# Convert presence/absence matrix to distance matrix

Tags: python, r, matrix

Because I don't want to draw a dendrogram using a presence/absence matrix, I have to obtain a distance matrix. 
Using it I can define some thresholds to plot some figures.

Presence/absence matrix:

```
Names   A   B   C   D   E   F   G   H   I
name1   1   1   0   1   1   1   1   1   0
name2   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   1   0
name3   1   0   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
name4   1   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   0
name5   0   1   0   1   1   0   1   1   0
```

And I want to convert it in a distance matrix like this:
The values do not correspond to the reality (this is the reason I am here).

```
        name1   name2   name3   name4   name5
name1   1.00    0.52    0.48    0.37    0.26
name2   0.52    1.00    0.47    0.21    0.93
name3   0.48    0.47    1.00    0.12    0.97
name4   0.37    0.21    0.12    1.00    0.86
name5   0.26    0.93    0.97    0.86    1.00
```

As a suggestion for this problem, I propose the solution that I found and included in the answers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To solve the problem I found an answer.

```
data = read.table("my_binary_file", sep="\t", header=T, row.names=1)
d = dist(data, method = "binary")
hc = hclust(d, method="complete")
write.table(as.matrix(d), file="dist_matrix.txt")
```

Sorry to disturb for nothing.